# How to filter tensorflow's Tensor based on tensor with indices?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Let's say I have a tensor of size `[batch_size, 5, 10]` called `my_tensor`.
I also have an another tensor of size `[batch_size, 1]` holding indices called `selecter`.

I want to filter `my_tensor` with respect to `selecter` to produce new tensor of size `[batch_size, 10]`, i.e. select only values that `selecter` contains. Basically, it's kinda reducing the middle dimension(which has size 5).

I feel like `tf.where` is the right choice, but not sure about it.
I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to go with `tf.gather_nd`.

```
tf.gather_nd(
    my_tensor,
    tf.stack([tf.range(batch_size), tf.squeeze(selecter)], axis=-1))
```

You can get rid of the `squeeze` if you construct `selecter` to be 1-D from the beginning.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using guys? I have 1.3.0 and my tf.gather_nd doesn't accept axis parameter. However, there is tf.gather that has it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, works in Tensorflow 1.3:

```
max_selecter = tf.reduce_max(selecter) + 1
my_tensor = tf.boolean_mask(
    outputs,
    tf.logical_xor(
        tf.sequence_mask(my_tensor + 1, max_selecter),
        tf.sequence_mask(my_tensor, max_selecter)
    )
)
```